# How to create a temporary value initialized T * in Standard-C++

Tags: c++, pointers, temporary, value-initialization

How to create a temporary value-initialized `T*` in standard C++?

```
void foo( int );
void bar( int * );

int main()
{
    foo( int() );  // works. a temporary int - value initialized.
    bar( ??? );    // how to create a temporary int *?
}
```

Just out of curiousity.

Comment: I think it's designed so that you can't create a temporary pointer, because doing such a thing doesn't make much sense. What would it point to? If nothing, juts use `nullptr`

Comment: Does `bar()` dereference the pointer, or is it "safe" to pass a pointer value that is illegal (i.e. points to unallocated memory)?

Comment: what's the purpose of that? just wondering.

Comment: @MarsonMao As I wrote: "Just out of curiousity." ... and because I were at a very uncreative state at the time asking that question and couldn't come up with an answer myself.

Comment: @Swordfish nice to know it ;) and it's really an old comment!

Comment: @MarsonMao I'm intrigued to delete the question, though, since it STILL attracts downvoters for no appearant reason :/

Comment: @Swordfish i see...lol but fortunately it has only 4 down-votes :p

Comment: @MarsonMao 2 up, 6 (!) down ... grrr.

Comment: @Swordfish dont worry, u got other good answers to compensate this one. just leave it as a history of ... life :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is to use curly braces:

```
 bar({});
```

Or a `using` statement:

```
using p = int*;
bar( p() );    // how to create a temporary int *?
```

[sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) just reminded me of the stupidly obvious answer of `nullptr`, `0`, and `NULL`.

```
bar(nullptr);
```

And I'm sure there's many more ways.

GCC lets you use compound literals, but technically this isn't allowed

```
 bar((int*){});
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a65dcb135a87ada

Comment: that's easier with `nullptr`

Comment: Yes, there's the ancient `NULL`, and the decrepit `0`. Aside from millions of variations on those themes.

Comment: using p = T*; is technically the same as a type alias introduced by typedef T* p; i guess?

Comment: @Swordfish: It's strictly equivalent. Still wondering about your post, why do those contortions?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Somehow I had it in my head he wanted default-initialization, but the question clearly says value-initialization, so I added `0` and `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, you can try a `typedef`:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo( int ) {}
typedef int* PtrInt;
void bar( PtrInt p ) 
{
   std::cout << "The value of p is " << p;
}

int main()
{
    foo( int() );  
    bar( PtrInt() );  
}
```

Live Example: http://ideone.com/sjOMlj

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use something like this:

```
int i=0;
bar(&i);  // safe to dereference in bar()
```

Or are you looking for an inliner? If so, you can use some frown-worthy casting, but then `bar()` shouldn't actually *dereference* that pointer:

```
bar((int*)0); // or use nullptr if your C++ compiler is more recent
```